# How to query dbpedia for baseball players full names and date of birth

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to query this ontology `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/BaseballPlayer` for full name and date of birth of each player but it seems like I'm doing something wrong.

Is this SPARQL query correct? Unfortunately it doesn't return any results.

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX onto: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT ?uri 
WHERE 
{
        ?subject rdfs:label 'baseball player'@en .
        ?uri foaf:givenName ?uri

}
```

Comment: **?subject rdfs:label 'baseball player'@en .** is obit going to find things that have the label 'baseball player'. Typically, the label of a dB Pedia resource is the title of the article. I'd suggest that you pick a real baseball player, look up the corresponding dbpedia resource, and see how the category information is represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * where {
  ?s a dbo:BaseballPlayer ;
     foaf:name ?name ;
     dbo:birthDate ?birthDate 
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fs%20a%20dbo%3ABaseballPlayer%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20foaf%3Aname%20%3Fname%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3AbirthDate%20%3FbirthDate%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: What if I want to get the team name too. Just the name not the URL. I tried `select * 
where {
 
              ?s a dbo:BaseballPlayer ;
              foaf:name ?name ;
              dbo:birthDate ?birthDate;
              dbo:team ?teams;
              foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf ?url
}` but it keeps returning the URL.

Comment: Lots of players have played for more than one team. When you browse the data for each player, which properties relate to the team that the player played for? Add that peppery or properties to your query. I don't have access to any information that you don't have access to, after all...

Comment: I added `dbo:team` and it works. Though, the returned value is URL not the English name of the team. I was wondering if there is a way to get the name directly instead of the URL

Comment: Again,you can browse the data that you're getting back... I'd expect that some property of that urls denoting the team probably has the name...